# Where can I make abstract algebra tangible?

Tags: abstract-algebra

In my text-book there is just an endless stream of theorems and it's just a big hot bowl of algebra with literally nothing to compare it all to.

I know that a relation is a specific form of connection between sets but my book decided that explaining what exactly, shouldn't matter. So I ask you: Is there any place I can go where I can get a tangible idea of what abstract algebra is? In other words, I could look up "relations" and see how they can be applied to less-abstract problems?

Comment: What book do you use?

Comment: A relation is a very rich structure that can represent many things. If you want to have something in mind, put the points of one of the sets on the first half of the page, the elements of the second set on the other half, and for every element of the relation an arrow pointing form an element of the first set to an element of the second set.

Comment: Bourbaki or Lang

Comment: My book is "Introduction to Abstract algebra" by D.S. Malik, Mordeson and Sen.

Comment: I found group actions and the various coloring problems of geometric solids and necklaces ("How many distinct necklaces of $n$ beads can be made with $k$ colors of beads?") to be quite concrete and tangible from the beginning.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action

Comment: Groups are used to described symmetry.  Artin's _Algebra_ often emphasizes the geometric aspects of group theory.

Comment: Gallians book also strives to always connect the theorems to concepts. I think youre just working with a non-introductory text